# In Amazon EC2, how do I make it run a python script when I "clone" that instance?

Tags: python, linux, unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Suppose I have a script in

```
/home/myuser/go.py
```

How do I run that script, when a new instance is booted?  (I'm used to using the point-and-click control panel Amazon has...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna try my nonexistent Linux skills here - create a shell script that runs your `go.py` and add a symlink to the shell script in `/etc/init.d/`

#### /home/myser/go.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
python /home/myuser/go.py
```

#### symlink

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/go.sh /home/myuser/go.sh
```

---

After reading up a bit myself, `/etc/rc.local` is probably a better place for this. Just edit it and add `/home/myuser/go.sh` there (again, make sure your `go.sh` is executable).

Comment: If I put it in init.d/, then will it start when the server instance is booted?

Comment: That's my understanding at least ;-) Make sure it's executable (i.e. `chmod a+x /etc/init.d/go.sh`)